# import pdfjslib into vuejs component

Tags: vue.js, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I would like to create a viewer PDF files into electron/vuejs application.

I need to use the pdfjs librarie.

For that I installed this package : `"pdfjs-dist": "2.6.347"`

and in my component vuejs I try to used this by doing this :

```
import pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist/webpack";
```

This import instruction seeems to be running good. But If a start used this like this :

```
created()
{
    pdfjsLib.getDocument()
}
```

I throw this error :

```
Cannot read property 'getDocument' of undefined"
```

I try lot of tricks but I don't find any solution for use this library in my component.

Anyone have a vuejs project with pdfjslib for viewing pdf ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
import("pdfjs-dist").then((pdfjsLib) => {
  pdfjsLib.getDocument();
});
```

It can be used inside either `created()` or `mounted()`. I'd personally use it in `mounted`.
Working demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-beaver-79eqh?file=/src/App.vue).

Also note calling `getDocument()` with no arguments seems to trigger some lib error (but that's outside the scope of current question):

> `Invalid parameter in getDocument, need either Uint8Array, string or a parameter object`

Comment: `getDocument("'./mypdf").then(...)` but I've got error: No "GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc" specified.

Comment: @NamLêQuý, consider asking a separate question. You're getting a different error than the one asked here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66879729/can-not-use-pdf-js-in-vue can u help me? thank you!

Comment: You must use `getDocument(this.urlFile).promise.then(...)` with the property promise